# Doctrine2: Lazy loading fails and I have to re-initialize the class

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I have three entities wallpost, albums and photos.

1. wallpost has many to one relationship with albums.
2. album has one to many relationship with photos.

When I post photos on my wall, the data goes into all three tables.
One record in wallpost, one in album and multiple in photos.

Now when I fetch data using

```
$wall_post_obj->getAlbum()->getId()
```

It shows id but when I try to fetch any other info such as

```
$wall_post_obj->getAlbum()->getName()
```

It returns NULL.

> This happens only when I delete one photo from album.

To get it work I have to re-initialize it using find query.
like this: `$em->find('\Entities\album',$id);`

---

*Extra information:*

The $wall_post_obj comes from following query:

```
        $qb_1 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $q_1 = $qb_1->select('wp, fromUsr.id, 
                              fromUsr.professional_image, 
                              fromUsr.gender, 
                              fromUsr.firstname, 
                              fromUsr.lastname')
        ->from( '\Entities\wall_post', 'wp' )
        ->LeftJoin( 'wp.wall_postsFrom_user', 'fromUsr' )
        ->where( 'wp.id IN (:selected_wp_ids_r)' )
        ->setParameter( 'selected_wp_ids_r', $selected_wp_ids_r )
        ->orderBy( 'wp.last_activity_datetime', 'DESC' );

        // wallpost Comments join
        $q_1->addSelect( 'wall_comments, comment_user' );
        $q_1->LeftJoin( 'wp.wall_postsComment', 'wall_comments' );
        $q_1->LeftJoin( 'wall_comments.commentsIlook_user', 'comment_user' );

        // wallpost Likes join
        $q_1->addSelect( 'likes' );
        $q_1->LeftJoin( 'wp.wall_postsLikes', 'likes' );
        $q_1->LeftJoin( 'likes.likesLiked_by', 'likedByUser' );

        $q_1 = $q_1->getQuery()->getResult ();
```

Comment: Maybe you could post the code of the relations inside the entities. And I guess that name in the album record is not null on db, right?

Comment: You could do a `$em->refresh($album);`

Comment: @pabgaran: it is not null.

Comment: @Jean: $em->refresh($album); is not working. It is showing following error message. Entity Entities\wall_post@00000000377f7af70000000020bee98f is not managed. An entity is managed if its fetched from the database or registered as new through EntityManager#persist

Comment: @Jean: But if I create new object of album using find query, it brings all the data and solves my problem. Like this: $em->find('\Entities\album', $id);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code was called in loop like below:

```
foreach( ...  )
{
     $wall_post_obj->getAlbum()
}
```

But accidentally $em->clear() was placed at the end of the loop.

$em->clear() clears the data from your current object. so $em->refresh() will not work.